# Filenames in string array c# Universal Windows

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows, universal

I am  developing an Universal Windows Platform app.
To continue i need the filenames from all files in one folder into a string array.
The get files Method doesnt work in UWP. I tried around with The Filepicker and Storagefolder but I dont know how to get it into a string array.

```
// C#
FolderPicker picker= new FolderPicker();
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*"); StorageFolder x = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", x);
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"path\to\Assets");
textBlock.Text = files.Length.ToString();
```

Comment: Add your existing code here, so we have something to go from.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Directory.EnumerateFiles`, `System.IO.Path.GetFileName` and LINQ :

```
string[] allFileNames = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirPath)
    .Select(System.IO.Path.GetFileName)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: I have no access to this folder. I tried with Directory.GetFiles(dirPath) and when i check for the length it says 0. These Windows Apps are Sandboxed

Answer (score 1):

> I have no access to this folder. I tried with Directory.GetFiles(dirPath) and when i check for the length it says 0. These Windows Apps are Sandboxed.

Yes you are right about this, in an UWP app, we can access to the app's local folder or some special lib like Music Library in the code behind, otherwise we need to use Folder/File Picker to let user choose to access the folder/file.

> I tried around with The Filepicker and Storagefolder but I dont know how to get it into a string array.

This is a correct direction and you can do this work using [StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) method like this:

```
private string[] filename;
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FolderPicker picker = new FolderPicker();
    picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.ComputerFolder;
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*"); //match all the file format

    StorageFolder folder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

    if (folder != null)
    {
        var subFiles = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
        filename = new string[subFiles.Count()];
        for (int i = 0; i < subFiles.Count(); i++)
        {
            filename[i] = subFiles.ElementAt(i).DisplayName;
            textBlock.Text = textBlock.Text + "+" + filename[i]; //show the file name in a textblock
        }
    }
}
```

Using `picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*")` can make the filter match all type of files in the folder, but these files will not be shown in the picker interface.